# Typescript: Is it possible to ensure the key and an inner value are the same string?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, type-constraints

I have a Record of data that could become large. I'm wondering if is it possible to enforce the key of the Record to be the same as the inner name value?.

```
interface Person<T> {
  name: T
  title: string
  description: string
}

type People = Record<string, Person<string>>

// example data

const data: People = {
  sarah: {
    name: 'sarah',
    title: 'Sarah',
    description: 'Hello',
  }
}

const badData: People = {
  adam: {
    name: 'john', // This would cause a typescript error ideally.
    ...
  }
}
```

I've tried setting up People with a generic but it would require me to add all the keys to a union type which I would rather avoid. `keyof` doesn't work as the object isn't defined where the `keyof` is needed.

```
type People<T> = Record<T, Person<T>>

const people: People<keyof typeof people> = {} // Block-scoped variable 'people' used before its declaration.ts(2448)
```

Comment: What if two people have the same name? It seems like `data` would be better off as an array.

Comment: The name is more like an id, the title is used for display purposes while the name is a unique reference to help with looks-ups. An object is more convenient as it allows for `data[personsName]` access rather than having to do indexOf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to do that, you need to use extra function.

```js
interface Person<T> {
    name: T
    title: string
    description: string
}

type People = Record<string, Person<string>>


type Validate<T extends People> = {
    [Name in keyof T]: Name extends T[Name]['name'] ? T[Name] : T[Name] & { name: never }
}


const validator = <
    Name extends string,
    Human extends Person<Name>,
    Data extends Record<Name, Human>
>(data: Validate<Data>) => data

const result = validator({
    sarah: {
        name: 'sarah',
        title: 'Sarah',
        description: 'Hello',
    },
    adam: {
        name: 'john', // Error.
        title: 'Sarah',
        description: 'Hello',
    }
})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=1&pln=14&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsQB4AqAfMgN4BQylyIcAthAFzL4VVjBgA2jyGYUoAOatKAEwgYEAgA7scTPgJDCAvmTJgAntJTos07sgC8yAEoQEWKKNyKhAGjSYct-kMKF1G7SgBqcTmBROEgCZAgAD0gQUQwnfW5iE3IqZABtADk6FFBkAGsITSwYZgBdJiz6cKiIGLj8TOzStIByGnoW0uQAfmZG%20i6mBsqILoAyUmpsphAIADdoZDU1dUsQPmQ5gKCQq2NkXBFkEero2N43ZXsjgAkAV1o4EFPa8-QobDwRwmvUgBEQnAXnUzBYrDYRo57o8QJ5CAAKYJgOBMfyBJEQXAA5GEACUxmISLgqxwGygEjunDA%20y26N2UHhKSoGDgUDgAAsmEzUpR2jwWiy2eyWr8eZR2Fx%20QBlVkckVHVLiSQyOQgJgtG4QTicLDy1IqUWUODBWhchVUPnqgBWWHZIBFyAA9I7kABRKBQKwAOnN4o43HVMqFerFyCVUmAsmA8mQGq1OpDlGWuKAA)

**`Validate`** iterates over each object `key`/`Name` and checks whether top level name is equal `Object[Name]['name']`. If yes - return same nested object. If no - return same nested object but with iverriden `name` proeprty `never`.

Hence, you are getting error in a place which should be fixed.

If you are interested in Type Inference on function arguments you can check my [article](https://catchts.com/infer-arguments)

More generic version of `Validation` from **@Konrad Madej**:

```js
type Validate<Data extends People> = {
    [Name in keyof Data]: Name extends Data[Name]['name'] ? Data[Name] : Omit<Data[Name], 'name'> & { name: Name }
}
```

If you have numeric keys, please consider this example:

```js
interface PayloadObj<T> {
    elementId: T;
    values: any;
}

type Payload = Record<number, PayloadObj<number>>;

type Validate<T extends Payload> = {
    [Key in keyof T]: T[Key] & { elementId: Key }
};

const validator = <
    ElementId extends number,
    PayloadValue extends PayloadObj<ElementId>,
    Data extends Record<ElementId, PayloadValue>
>(data: Validate<Data> & Data): Payload => data;

const result = validator({
    0: {
        elementId: 0,
        values: 'Hello',
    },
    1: {
        elementId: 2, // Error.
        values: 'World',
    },
});
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wQYx7w)

Comment: BTW in case anyone decides to go wit this solution you can improve the error you get by changing the validator a tiny bit:

`[Name in keyof Data]: Name extends Data[Name]['name'] ? Data[Name] : Omit<Data[Name], 'name'> & { name: Name }`

Comment: @KonradMadej thank you! Feel free to update the answer. Have a nice weekend :)

Comment: Had no idea I could do that  Haven't used stack overflow for a while  Anyway it says the suggested edit queue is full so no can do 

Comment: @KonradMadej made an update

Comment: Why do I get an error `Type '"name"' cannot be used to index type 'T[Name]'` when making the record key a number?

Comment: @T.Gaud please provide an example

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApwJ4BsD2cAmA8gEYBWAPACoB8yA3gFDLPIRYQC2E4AkvgFzJKAbiYsAbnCwBXCAGdBcEBlEBfBgzAYADinTY8+ZAF5kAJQgIcUfORDSOxaABo0mXARIV7j6NWqimjooAGpSwPhwkFSsAB6QIPhybgYEtKaMLMgA2gDSEBjIoMgA1gU4MEIAuoL5hRDx3ElCeQVV2QDkbJzcYHwdVcgA-C11g4KUrRiDAGT0rOxcvALIIBDi0MiqaoFWIHJgyJJYEVHWJsjkYswAoou9fHEJzT5OUK7XKR74YTIoDc9kvpvl5yHcestqB8sgARKJwJ5NZIWKw2MH3ZauYGGX6yagMagACkiYDggl+p2icNJ1AAlIJsQQTLQSXBdjh9ocoPJpFhDqZjpTrITMiwAAyCUVZZjdJZ9FZi5yfLLHWQKZAdAASbFwHSVWVU+pYAEZJcqWLKHisAKyuAD0duQNygUGsADpzcxVfJBB0AOrWLD4PWfQ0MVS04RAA

Comment: @T.Gaud you need to make sure that Key is a number. See [here](https://tsplay.dev/WvaARm)

Comment: thanks @captain-yossarianfromUkraine, but the validation no longer works then. In your example the key and the id can be different numbers without throwing an error

Comment: @T.Gaud I am unable to explain why there is an error but I can provide you with fix. See [here](https://tsplay.dev/wQYx7w)