# Typescript: Constraint property value based on key in parent object

Tags: typescript

in my project I want to enforce rule on an object which can be stated as **String property in child object has to be same as key of the object in it's parent**. Simplified for the demo it should work like this:

```
const profile: {
   languages: {
      // Should be valid!
      english: { name: "english" },
      // Should not be valid! (either key should be "italian" or name "spanish")
      spanish: { name: "italian" }
   }
}
```

**Please note that I understand I could do something like this:**

```
export type Profile<TLanguageNames> = {
  languages: Languages<TLanguageNames>;
};

export type Languages<TLanguageNames> = {
  readonly [TLanguageName in keyof TLanguageNames]?: {
    readonly name: TLanguageName;
  };
};

const fields: Profile<{ english: ""; french: "" }> = {
  languages: {
    english: { name: "english" },
  },
};
```

My problem is that there are multiple layers between `Profile` and `Languages` so I do not want to pass `TLanguageNames` through all these layers.

May I please ask if there is a way how to achieve this and let typescript "infer" the type without creating generic type?

```
// I understand why this does not work but this is basically what I would like to achieve:
export type Languages = {
  // Let TS know that TLanguageName can be any string
  readonly [TLanguageName in string]: { 
    // But once I write that string make TS force me to use the same string here
    readonly name: TLanguageName;
  };
};

// Obviously in the example above this is allowed since TLanguageName can be any string
const fields: Languages = {
  english: { name: "french" },
};
```

Comment: The only facility TS has to represent something like this is with generics.  You can either pass the generics around your whole code base, or you could possibly try to encode existentially-quantified generics... but given your examples I don't understand at all the need for this sort of complexity; why require `name` at all if the object holding it has the value as the key?  You can always produce it from the `languages` property as needed.  Anyway, all three basic approaches are shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/wR1xnW). Which of these, if any, would you like to explore as a solution to the q?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript: Is it possible to ensure the key and an inner value are the same string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69417437/typescript-is-it-possible-to-ensure-the-key-and-an-inner-value-are-the-same-str)

Comment: @jcalz - thank you for looking at this. All your points are fair but please note that I provided only simplified version of the domain (also this structure is something I have to deal with in older project and I just want to make it type-safe). 

Your solutions:
1st. -> this solution requires me to specify allowed keys manually - by providing union of keys (which is what I am trying to avoid)
3rd. -> this solution would not work for me as language object does not contain only `name` property

Comment: @jcalz - 2nd. solution is closest to what I am trying to achieve (and I believe it's same as described in link provided by Henry - unfortunately it does not answer my question). 

It is exactly what I need in a sense that it does not force me to specify type of the language keys manually and at the same time once I type `{ english: { } }`, it forces me to use the same string in name property. 

The only thing is that I would need to implement this behaviour without using function.

Comment: Then it's impossible? TS doesn't have native support for existential generics.  Would you rather have the answer be "this is impossible" or "you need to refactor"?

Comment: Yeap, it's totally fair to reply that what I am trying to achieve is impossible and I am fine with that answer!

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77855703/typescript-constraint-property-value-based-on-key-in-parent-object?noredirect=1#comment137256243_77855703) @MiroslavGregor Which languages are supported? By maintaining the list in the type system, you won’t need generics **and** you’ll be able to validate that the user defined a valid language name.

Comment: Thanks @jsejcksn, I understand that it would make it easier to have list of allowed values. Also I know that it might not make sense to keep that design and I appreciate you spent time looking at this, but none of this is really point of the question. I can as well change the example to `const formFields = { email: { name: "email" }`. Question was simply `Is it possible to do this?` i.e. to define type `MyType` (no generics), type: `const sth: MyType = { whatever: { name: ` and at this point have TS to suggest and allow only to pass `"whatever"`? (thanks to jcalz I know it currently isn't :) )